# VBA delete sheets where sheet name like "M######"

Tags: vba, excel

Any idea how to delete all sheets whose name is like "M######"? For example, I may have M124598, M999999, M650123, etc. Tried using the wildcard, but no success. Thank you!

```
For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If s.Name = "M######" Then
    s.Delete
End If
Next s
```

Comment: Show what you tried, because most of the examples on SO doing the same thing work, so there must be something wrong in the way you are doing it.  (It might be simply that you need to use `"M??????"` instead of `"M######"`, but we can't tell until we see the actual code you used.)

Comment: Just added...sorry about that. Thanks!

Comment: `If s.Name like "M######" Then`

Comment: @ScottCraner TIL that "#" is a valid wildcard character

Comment: @YowE3K `#` is valid for a single number.

Comment: Is there a numeric wildcard I can use? Just in case someone adds a tab named "MASTERS" or something like that.

Comment: The issue is not the wildcard but the need to use `Like` instead of `=`

Comment: @ERKSMTY See Scott's comment - `"#"` is valid (I just didn't realise it) - so it is just the `Like` -v- `=` that is causing the problem

Comment: see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator

Comment: ^^ Or better still, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/like-operator (That's the VBA documentation, the other one is the VB.Net documentation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`If s.Name = "M######"` will be `True` when `s.Name` *is exactly equal to* `M######`.

If you want to be able to use placeholders, look into the `Like` statement, as @Scott mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121379/vba-delete-sheets-where-sheet-name-like-m#comment83219418_48121379).

> ```
> If s.Name like "M######" Then
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
If Left(s.Name,1) = "M" and Len(s.Name) = 7 Then s.Delete
Next s
```